# How to upgrade glsl version from 1.2 on MAC

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl, version, pyopengl

hello I'm using Pyopengl on mac using PyCharm.
my laptop is macbook pro 2016, 4 thunderbolts.

and as you can see from the code, glsl version is 1.2 
I tried all the other numbers to check whether it works but only version 120 worked.

I really want to use glsl version over 3.3 and want to know it is possible or not.

I don't understand why my version is so low even though my laptop is not that old one.

```
vertex_src = """
# version 120 

uniform mat4 rotation;

attribute vec3 a_position; 
attribute vec3 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texture;

varying vec3 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texture;

void main(void)
{
    v_color = a_color;
    gl_Position  = rotation * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_texture = a_texture;

    //v_texture = 1- a_texture;                       //flip texture vertically and horizontally
    //v_texture = vec2(a_texture.s, 1-a_texture.t);   //flip texture vertically
}
"""
```

Comment: Why don't you think anything higher than 1.20 is available?  What happens if you try `#version 330 core` ?

Comment: You'll have to use a core profile context to get OpenGL > 2.1 on MacOS